# Comparing two columns, finding mismatches and pasting entire row in a new worksheet using VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a macro in VBA that will compare values in two different columns, find the mismatches and then copy and paste the entire row of the mismatched value to a new worksheet.  My code is below.

My code works doing this with the individual values (which I commented out below) but when I try to copy and paste the entire row, that's when things don't work.

```
Public Sub CompareNumber(sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet)

Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range

lr1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Get the last row with data for both list sheets
lr2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


Set rng1 = sh1.Range("B2:B" & lr1) 'Establish the ranges on both sheets
Set rng2 = sh2.Range("B2:B" & lr2)


    For Each c In rng1 'Run a loop for each list, ID mismatches and paste to sheet 3.

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, c.Value) = 0 Then

            c.EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.End(xlUp)(2)
            'sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value

        End If
    Next

    For Each c In rng2

        If Application.CountIf(rng1, c.Value) = 0 Then

            c.EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.End(xlUp)(2)
            'sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)(2) = c.Value

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "things don't work" isn't a very useful description of your problem - what happens exactly?

Comment: `c.EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: @Tim Williams the problem is not all mismatches are shown on sheet3 when trying to copy the entire row of range c when the for each loop runs.  It's as if there are missing mismatches. As mentioned identifying the mismatched values isn't a problem.

Comment: Without any sample data it's impossible to know what a "missing mismatch" might be due to - possible trailing/leading spaces in your data?  In the source data is ColumnA always populated?  If not that will cause problems when pasting rows to sh3 - an empty cell in colA will cause the next-pasted row to overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source data is ColumnA always populated? If not that will cause problems when pasting rows to sh3 - an empty cell in colA will cause the next-pasted row to overwrite the previous one.

Something like this is a bit safer (plus a little refactoring to abstract out the repeated loop):

```
Public Sub CompareNumber(sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet)

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngDest As Range

    'Establish the ranges on both sheets
    Set rng1 = sh1.Range(sh1.Range("B2"), sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = sh2.Range(sh2.Range("B2"), sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    Set rngDest = sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    CopyMismatches rng1, rng2, rngDest
    CopyMismatches rng2, rng1, rngDest

End Sub

Private Sub CopyMismatches(rngSrc As Range, rngMatch As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rngSrc
        If Application.CountIf(rngMatch, c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy rngDest
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) '<< safer if could be empty colA values
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim your solution worked!  To answer your question Column A is always populated however the two columns being compared will vary in size.  Thank you for your expert help.  Kuddos!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
"sh1.rows(c1.row).EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.End(xlUp)(2)" 
instead of
 "c.EntireRow.Copy sh3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.End(xlUp)(2)"

This may work

Comment: Hi Arun - thanks for your suggestion but I'm getting the same result as with the original code.